# Is "X is known difficult to implement" correct?

Tags: grammaticality

Is either of the following correct?

> X is known difficult to implement.
>   X is known to be difficult to implement.

Answer (score 4):

The only one of your choices that is a complete sentence is this:

> X is known to be difficult to implement.

And there are verbs which fit the other structure, such as *find*, with which the *to be* is unnecessary:

> X has been found [to be] difficult to implement.

*Know* with that usage, when it has ever occurred, has been archaic (*He knew the climb dangerous*).

Comment: Searching Google books, it appears that the incorrect usage may not even be archaic; it appears to be used mainly by writers of technical papers with Chinese, Japanese, or Korean names.

Answer (score 0):

The first expression is possible with *difficult to implement* as an adjective, that is, a noun follows it:

> X is **a** known *difficult to implement* plan.

Note, however, the added article **a**. It is also better to hyphenate the phrase (difficult-to-implement) or find a one-word substitute, except where the phrase is a recognized or defined term, such as in a particular field or within a particular document.